# Spring boot - holding authenticated user through many server instances

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-security

I have got spring security `STATELESS` application based on `JWT` tokens. Here is my custom authorization filter

```kotlin
override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        chain: FilterChain,
    ) {
        val header = request.getHeader(Objects.requireNonNull(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
        if (header != null) {
            val authorizedUser = tokensService.parseAccessToken(header)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authorizedUser
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
```

so as you can see, I save the `authorizedUser` into `SecurityContextHolder`.
Then I use this saved user to e.g. secure my app before retrieving data of user `A` by user `B` like this:

```kotlin
    @Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    @PreAuthorize("authentication.principal.toString().equals(#employerId.toString())")
    annotation class IsEmployer


    @IsEmployer
    @GetMapping("/{employerId}")
    fun getCompanyProfile(@PathVariable employerId: Long): CompanyProfileDTO {
        return companyProfileService.getCompanyProfile(employerId)
    }
```

But it works when the app runs as a single instance while I would like to deploy this app on many intances so the

```kotlin
authentication.principal.toString().equals(#employerId.toString()
```

will no work anymore becuase context holders are different on different instances.

Comment: What error are you seeing? The filter (which populates SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication) is in the same instance that processes getCompanyProfile, so authentication should be available.

Comment: but what happens if authentication request goes to instance `A`, but then the request getCompanyProfile goes to instance `B`. Then the SecurityContextHolder will be empty on the instance `B` or am I wrong?

Comment: Its ONE request. For any request the ServletFilter (authentication) is ALWAYS on the same server as the ServletController that processes it. The filterChain passes the request on to the controller and has the same security context. With JWT every single request is authenticated (because every request goes through the filter) and allows the service to be stateless. The advantage of this is scalability - you can have as many instances as you need.

Comment: well, man learns something new everyday.
Great, I thought I need to use redis or any other external db to store security context. 
Thanks a lot, u made my day

Comment: This is a valuable question and answer. I have created an answer.  Can you please accept it. I think it would be helpful to many.

Comment: sure, one more question btw. Do `csrf` tokens work the same or do I need to manage this in special way when using many server instances

Comment: If you are STATELESS there is no session so CSRF cannot be used. Each request has the JWT Bearer header.

Comment: what if I store a `refresh token` as a `secure` `httpOnly` cookie but this cookie is only used to asking for new `accessToken` which is stored in a state and this `accessToken` is send in other requests as an `Authorization` header. 
Isn't there a possibility to steal the `refresh token`?

Comment: Very unlikely with https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any request the ServletFilter (authentication) is ALWAYS on the same server as the ServletController that processes it. The filterChain passes the request on to the controller and has the same security context. With JWT every single request is authenticated (because every request goes through the filter) and allows the service to be stateless. The advantage of this is scalability - you can have as many instances as you need.